# categories for chi-square test of independence - what if categories are determined by TWO variables?

Tags: chi-squared-test

My categories are the combination of two variables.  For example if I have two age bands and two sexes, the categories are
old women,
young women,
old men, and
young men

So on the one hand there are four categories and I'm looking at how people selected plan A or plan B across those categories.  So I can mechanically perform the chi-sq test.  But is it valid in a theoretical sense?  Is there any theoretical reason why I shouldn't use the test because of how the categories are actually formed by smooshing two variables together (technical term).  Is there some other test I should use instead?

Edited following initial answer:

Great! I'm also doing logistic regression with a number of additional IVs. Am I correct in expecting broad agreement betw chi-square test results and logistic regression results?

Comment: What is important is what you want to find out; if chi-squared on your 2x4 table addresses what you wanted to know, it should be fine. You could alternatively construct a 2x2x2 array ('table') and answer a variety of possible questions using chi squared, or do approximately the same thing (answer the same questions) via binomial (e.g. logistic) regression.

Comment: I've taken what you suggested in editing my answer and placed it instead into your question. That will be easier for later visitors to the site to follow. I suspect that you wanted to leave a comment but don't (yet) have enough reputation to do that. I've also expanded my answer to address that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chi-square test can be used for any contingency table where you are comparing observed counts against the counts expected among categories under a null hypothesis. So you could construct a 2 (`planChoice`) x 4 (`age`/`sex` combinations) contingency table and do a chi-square test on that table.

Another, more generally applicable approach would be to do a logistic regression with the binary `planChoice` as the outcome variable. Then you could get around your arbitrary old/young age cutoff and model `age` as a continuous predictor, including `sex` as a categorical predictor and an interaction of `age` with `sex` to see if the association of `planChoice` with `age` differs depending on `sex`.

If you want to include continuous covariates in your model or have a large number of predictors, some form of binomial regression is preferable. Logistic regression is the most familiar such model, but you should know that other "link" functions besides the logit it employs can have their uses.

In terms of agreement among tests, even the results of two "chi-square tests" on the same data will differ if one test uses the "continuity correction" (the default in R) and the other test doesn't (perhaps a better choice). The inherently discrete nature to the probability distribution in a contingency table means that nominal p-vales in chi-square tests don't always correspond to actual false-positive rates under the null hypothesis. Results with logistic regression thus will generally agree with those from a chi-square test, but not necessarily exactly.